# ValueTuple does not support DisplayMemberPath. Combobox, WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-7.0, valuetuple

I have a combobox and want to bind its ItemsSource to an `IEnumerable<(string,string)>`. If I do not set DisplayMemberPath, then it works and it shows in the dropdown area the result of calling `ToString()` in the items. Nevertheless when I set `DisplayMemberPath="Item1"` it does not show anything anymore. I have made the following sample in which you may see that if I use classic `Tuple` type it works as expected.

When debugging I have checked that the valuetuple has Item1 and Item2 as properties also.

My XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TupleBindingTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Loaded="MainWindow_OnLoaded"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ComboBox x:Name="TupleCombo" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                  DisplayMemberPath="Item1" />
        <ComboBox x:Name="ValueTupleCombo" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                  DisplayMemberPath="Item1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And my codebehind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace TupleBindingTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>> GetTupleData()
        {
            yield return Tuple.Create("displayItem1", "valueItem1");
            yield return Tuple.Create("displayItem2", "valueItem2");
            yield return Tuple.Create("displayItem3", "valueItem3");
        }

        private IEnumerable<(string, string)> GetValueTupleData()
        {
            yield return ( "displayItem1", "valueItem1");
            yield return ("displayItem2", "valueItem2");
            yield return ("displayItem3", "valueItem3");
        }

        private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TupleCombo.ItemsSource = GetTupleData();
            ValueTupleCombo.ItemsSource = GetValueTupleData();
        }
    }
}
```

At runtime this sample will show the data properly in the first combobox but will show nothing in the second.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's because `DisplayMemberPath` internally sets binding with the specified path for each item's template. So setting `DisplayMemberPath="Item1"` is basically shorthand for setting following `ComboBox.ItemTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Item1}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Now *WPF* only supports binding to properties. That's why it works fine when you use `Tuple`s - because its members are **properties**, and also why it does not work with `ValueTuple`s - because its members are **fields**.

In your particular case though, since you use these collections solely as binding sources, you could use *anonymous types* to achieve your goal (its members are also **properties**), e.g.:

```
private IEnumerable<object> GetTupleData()
{
    yield return new { Label = "displayItem1", Value = "valueItem1" };
    yield return new { Label = "displayItem2", Value = "valueItem2" };
    yield return new { Label = "displayItem3", Value = "valueItem3" };
}
```

Then you could set up your `ComboBox` with:

```
<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Label" SelectedValuePath="Value" (...) />
```

Comment: Moral of the story, the items of a `ValueTuple` are exposed as fields and not properties, and WPF doesn't support binding to fields.